# Higlight GeoPoints of PathOverlay with a bubble

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

I'm OSMdroid for laying overlays for offline maps. Is there a possiblity that pathOverlays can be pointed out with any bubble or big dot, everytime a path is traversed?

My pathOverlay is updated by a AsyncTask, and as and when new GeoPoint is received, path is redrawn. How can I higlight the points of pathOverlay?

Comment: Try something and get back to us in case of trouble. The short answer is Yes, you may have to override your `PathOverlay`.

Comment: a heads up as to lead which way or using which technique would be fine.

Comment: You have access to the GeoPoints and to the Canvas of your overlay when inheriting from it. So you can create circles you will display each time the location is updated. It might be even better (more efficient / simple) to get inspired from the PathOverlay to create your own one, that would do that on top of drawing the path.

Comment: i'd tried that, but with the overlay it redraws everytime i pan or zoom. I even tried restricting the draw at times, which would be out of visible portion, didn't succeed fully. But I notice a performance degradation when path overlay or polygon overlay similar kind of overlays were used. So, I decided to go with `ItemizedOverlayItem` which would just place a dot, and subsequent dots would be like a line. Seems like this is working for now, but not very effective.

Comment: I think you can have a middleground approach: what about extending `ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>` in a way it would spot a `drawable`at each location and trace a line between these locations? Your former approach was maybe good though, even if not yet successful.

Comment: Oh, BTW, you might be interested in the OsmBonusMap lib: https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_5 - It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, i already had a look at that!